# Flutter - Riverpod 2.0 - How to access onDispose callback?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have this class

```
class EntryController {
  final TabController? tabController;
  final List<DictionaryEntry> history;

  EntryController({
    required this.history,
    this.tabController,
  });

  EntryController copyWith({
    TabController? tabController,
    List<DictionaryEntry>? history,
  }) {
    return EntryController(
      history: history ?? this.history,
      tabController: tabController ?? this.tabController,
    );
  }
}
```

And i have this Riverpod notifier

```
@riverpod
class ExpandedEntryController extends _$ExpandedEntryController {
  @override
  EntryController build() {
    return EntryController(
      history: [],
    );
  }

  void updateState(EntryController controller) => state = controller;

  void seeRelatedWord(DictionaryEntry relatedWord) {
    state.history.add(relatedWord);
    state.tabController!.animateTo(0);
  }

  void onDispose() {
    state.tabController!.dispose();
  }
}
```

I know that by default it has de autoDispose( ) method, but when it disposes i suppose i should dispose the `tabController` right? How should i do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct your code like this:

```
@riverpod
class ExpandedEntryController extends _$ExpandedEntryController {
  @override
  EntryController build() {

    ref.onDispose(() {
      state.tabController?.dispose();
    });

    return EntryController(
      history: [],
    );
  }
```

You can also use `ref.watch` or `ref.listen` safely in the `build` method of your notifier.

Comment: I had no idea i could use those inside the build method. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Don't override `this.onDispose()`!.  Add

```
ref.onDispose(() => state.tabController?.dispose());
```

to your `build()`.  That should take care of disposing that controller when this controller goes away.